# Removing triples from imported rdf files in a GraphDB repository

Tags: rdf, graphdb

I am new to GraphDB and RDF. Currently my repository consists of multiple .ttl files that I have imported separately. If I delete a previously imported file from the import window, the triples remain in the repository. The only way I can see to remove triples from the repository is to clear the repository completely (**Explore>Graphs overview>Clear repository**), and then re-import all of the files I want manually (**Import>RDF**).

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? Ideally I would want to remove the .ttl files from the list on the import page and then refresh the repository only with the files that remain. Is this possible or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: The simplest way will be to import the data from each of the files into a separate context (named after the file) and just drop the context when you decide to do so.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'context' I have searched the documentation but I have not found any examples of this approach. Are you able to elaborate on what you mean? Thanks

Comment: `context` is a `named graph` . When you click on `Import` you see `Import Settings` dialog. There is a field `Target graphs` with few options above (`From data`, `The default graph` and `Named graph`. Select `Named graph` and type something meanigfull as a IRI, e.g. file:my-datafile.ttl for instance. That way all the statements from the file will be placed in a this named graph (context). Then you could remove these through `Graphs overview` screen or via sparql update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Damyan's answer, removing the files in the Import page does not remove them from the repository - it removes them from the list. The best approach is Damyan's - this way you can easy track your changes. You can find more information on managing graphs in the documentation - http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/sparql-compliance.html